# PostgreSQL - How to suppress query statement message

Tags: sql, postgresql, command-line, suppressmessage

I use a file where I have all my SQL queries. I run the following command:

```
psql -U postgres -d rails_development -a -f ProjectApp/db/Query.sql
```

Output is as following:

```
SELECT * FROM "Users"
id | username | firstname | lastname | [...]
...
(27 rows)
```

I would like to remove query message (SELECT * FROM "Users") from output. Is that possible?

Comment: Remove the `-a` flag. (and *maybe* add the `-t` flag) NOTE: `psql --help` gives you all the possible flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-a` or `--echo-all` echoes all input from script. You won't need that. Include `--tuples-only` or the `-t` flag to print rows only like so:

> psql -U postgres -d rails_development --tuples-only -f ProjectApp/db/Query.sql

`psql --help` says:

```
...
Input and output options:
  -a, --echo-all           echo all input from script
  -e, --echo-queries       echo commands sent to server
  ...

Output format options:
  ...
  -R, --record-separator=STRING
                           set record separator (default: newline)
  -t, --tuples-only        print rows only
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The -a option repeats every query on the terminal (STDOUT), you want to remove this option from your commandline.